# window.requestFileSystem fails in android phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using window.requestFileSystem in android. But it fails with **error code 9**. I have read [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/rgStH2USABY) the issue with android devices not having SD card. This is the code I am using

```
window.requestFileSystem(2, 0, function(file_system) {
                console.log('got fs');
                callback(null, file_system);
            }, function(err) {
                console.log('not getting library fs'+err.code);
                callback(err);
            });
```

How can I use this in android?

Answer (score 0):

According to official documents, the first parameter in `requestFileSystem` should be a constant `LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT` or `LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY`

try the following standard statement:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(f){ /* sucess */ }, function(e){ /* error */);
```